# Bounds of an ImageButton

Tags: java, android, libgdx, scene2d

I have a button (reloadButton) which is an `ImageButton`

I want to `setBounds()` to it but the problem is its `ImageButtonStyle.imageUp` and `ImageButtonStyle.imageDown` are rounded images and I don't want to make the bounds rectangle as this button can be touched

How can I `setBounds` to this button ?

Here is my code

```
TextureRegion buttonUp = Assets.getTextureRegion(Assets.getTextureAtlas(Assets.reloadButton), "up"); 

TextureRegion buttonDown = Assets.getTextureRegion(Assets.getTextureAtlas(Assets.reloadButton), "down"); 

ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle buttonStyle = new ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle(); 

buttonStyle.imageUp = new TextureRegionDrawable(buttonUp); 

buttonStyle.imageDown = new TextureRegionDrawable(buttonDown); 

reloadButton = new ImageButton(buttonStyle);

 // reloadButton.addListener()
```

Comment: could you provide your current code?

Comment: I don't think you can be that specific with `setBounds`. You could override `Actor.fire(Event)` method and check if your rounded rectangle contains the point (you would need radius though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actor bounds are always a rectangle. If you want to test a different shape, override the `hit` method of your Actor. For example, for a rounded rectangle, subclass ImageButton and do this (where `rad` is the corner radius):

```
@Override
public Actor hit (float x, float y, boolean touchable) {
    Actor hit = super.hit(x, y, touchable); //is in rectangle

    if (hit != null){ //reject corners if necessary
        boolean keep = true;
        if (x < rad){
            if (y < rad) keep = inCircle(x, y, rad, rad, rad);
            else if (y > getHeight() - rad) keep = inCircle(x, y, rad, getHeight() - rad, rad);
        } else if (x > getWidth() - rad){
            if (y < rad) keep = inCircle(x, y, getWidth() - rad, rad, rad);
            else if (y > getHeight() - rad) keep = inCircle(x, y, getWidth() - rad, getHeight() - rad, rad);
        }
        if (!keep) hit = null;
    }
    return hit;
}

private boolean inCircle(float x, float y, float centerX, float centerY, float radius) {
    float dx = x - centerX;
    float dy = y - centerY;
    return dx * dx + dy * dy <= radius * radius;
}
```

Comment: but super.hit(x, y, touchable) return Actor not boolean

Comment: @MAGS94 Oops! Fixed.